# Reversing the package name change in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, package, refactoring

I renamed my package in Eclipse which produced an undesirable result. How do I revert to the original name?

When I try to refactor, I get the error message "Save ALL Failed,   Illegal Value: -1

Comment: Did you try to Undo?

Comment: Thanks nitind. I was able to Undo the name change.